# What is the technical term for certain circles?

Tags: geometry, terminology

[image]

I am writing up some notes on equilateral triangles. I have reached the point where I want to show that a triangle is equilateral if and only if the three circles P, Q, and R, in the above diagram are congruent. I know the proof; my problem is I don't know how to refer to these circles. Is there a technical term I can use when referring to tangent circles such as these?

Comment: Apollonian circles when included in bigger circles. I don't know about triangles. Maybe just inscribed circles.

Comment: I would draw the picture, and just the label the circles by the letters you've just used. As they say, a picture can be worth a thousand words. Probably less, actually, but still better than trying to use some obscure term.

Comment: Related question: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/26746/inscribed-kissing-circles-in-an-equilateral-triangle. They mention kissing circles :-)

Comment: @ChristopherA.Wong. What you suggest is probably what I will do if no one comes up with a succinct term. I was hoping there was some common term that I was ignorant of, not being a professional mathematician.

Comment: @ja72. Thanks for the reference -- "kissing circles" may do although it's just a general synonym of "tangent circles" -- if nothing more specific comes up.

Comment: Taking @ja72 mention of "Apollonian circles" as a Google search term, I found that my diagram is the second stage of an Apollonian packing of an equilateral triangle.

Comment: How about something like "stage-2 incircles," or "second-order incircles"? There are exactly $3^{n-1}$ $n$th order incircles.

Comment: @LordSoth. I like "2nd-order incircles". I think I'll go with that. If you write it up, I'll accept it.

Comment: Now that I have looked at Apollonian packings, I can see that the proposition I am considering can be extended to any stage of the packing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because it doesn't look like LordSoth is going to post an answer, I'm recording the suggestion he made for the record.

Of all terms suggested, I find *second order in-circle* the most descriptive of the concept I wanted to capture. I am using this term in the notes I am writing.
The term has the advantage of generalization to *n-th order in-circle*, which would be a tangent circle added at the n-th stage of an Apollonian packing of a triangle. Indeed, the proposition stated in my question holds at any stage of an Apollonian packing.

Answer (score 1):

I might as well try to get the accepted answer with "Kissing Circles", and "Apollonian Circles" and an alternate.

See related question [Inscribed kissing circles in an equilateral triangle](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/26746/3301).

And http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ApolloniusCircle.html

Comment: Sorry and thanks for your contribution, but I like  "2nd-order incircles" better.

Comment: Great. Now you or someone needs to put this as an answer to the question.